# LUKS password correct, but not accepted

Tags: partition, kali-linux, grub2, luks, disk-encryption

I am attempting to install Kali on a laptop, which should normally be straightforward. However, on this particular device, the Kali installer errors upon writing the partition changes to disk for some reason. I was previously able to get around this issue by partitioning the drive manually via `fdisk`. Kali was running great. However, I was lacking disk encryption. So, I wiped the drive and set out to partition and configure Kali manually, with LUKS encryption.

I found an article for this which I was able to follow with only a few deviations
https://devconnected.com/how-to-encrypt-root-filesystem-on-linux/
The partition scheme I ended up with is as follows

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000LPVX-7
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C6EB1185-05CF-4E8D-ABAC-1376C75628F8

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1953791   1951744   953M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  1953792   3907583   1953792   954M EFI System
/dev/sda3  3907584 976773119 972865536 463.9G Linux filesystem
```

With `sda1` as `/boot` (needed due to BIOS legacy boot things), `sda2` as `/boot/efi` and `sda3` as my root encrypted filesystem. This scheme worked for an unencrypted Kali install, so all I needed was to setup LUKS.

Using `cryptsetup` as detailed in the article I have the following for `sda`

```
$ lsblk                      
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                  8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1               8:1    0   953M  0 part  
├─sda2               8:2    0   954M  0 part  
└─sda3               8:3    0 463.9G  0 part  
  └─crypto         254:0    0 463.9G  0 crypt 
    ├─cryptVG-swap 254:1    0     2G  0 lvm   
    └─cryptVG-root 254:2    0 461.9G  0 lvm
```

I am running Kali on a live USB to setup my laptop hard drive, and the article details moving an existing OS install over to an encrypted install. I can't `rsync` the live medium files and have the OS work like an actual (not live) install, so I simply used Kali's installer to write the install to a USB as if it were a hard drive (unsure why the installer writes partitions fine to a USB yet not my disk, but w/e). I was then able to mount both and rsync the USB's root file system to my encrypted disk. This seemed to work like a charm.

I was also able to reinstall grub as detailed without major issues, after a small change in that section. Basically I used `--rbind` when mounting `/dev` before chrooting to avoid a sudo error, and I also needed to mount/bind proc before chrooting too. After chrooting successfully I still got an error stating that the hostname "kali" couldn't be resolved anytime I ran sudo, but it didn't seem to impact the commands I was running so I ignored it.

My grub setup ended up as follows:

UUIDs

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL     UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                               
├─sda1
│    vfat   FAT32           9080-831D                                             
├─sda2
│    vfat   FAT32           345D-5BB8                                             
└─sda3
     crypto 2               f0b2bee7-9566-4178-9a3a-6ffee87482df                  
  └─crypto
     LVM2_m LVM2            6t1L5r-GdTD-Fda4-A3D7-OjMI-DiI9-mKM76J                
    ├─cryptVG-swap
    │  swap   1               9d7471b5-cd00-477b-a599-48517194122c                  
    └─cryptVG-root
       ext4   1.0             740ca216-99a9-46ee-a2c2-fa2dbde2ccb7    417.1G     3% /mnt
```

/etc/fstab

```
$ cat /mnt/etc/fstab 
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# root
UUID=740ca216-99a9-46ee-a2c2-fa2dbde2ccb7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# efi
UUID=345D-5BB8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap
UUID=9d7471b5-cd00-477b-a599-48517194122c none            swap    sw              0       0
```

/etc/crypttab

```
$ cat /mnt/etc/crypttab 
# <target name> <source device>     <key file>  <options>
crypt UUID=f0b2bee7-9566-4178-9a3a-6ffee87482df none luks
```

Based on these configs it *seems* like I should be able to boot into the OS fine. I have the UUIDs correct as far as I can tell and I have grub stage 1 installed fine because it prompts me for a password to unlock the device. However, while I am able to unlock `/dev/sda3` with my password using `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 crypto`, using this same password on the boot screen gives me an incorrect password error.

Upon booting into `sda` I see

```
Enter passphrase for hd0,gpt3 (f0b2bee7-9566-4178-9a3a-6ffee87482df):
```

And upon entering the correct password it immediately prints

```
error: Invalid passphrase
error: no such cryptodisk found
error: disk `lvmid/kJKtcZ-eQPE-zpEE-r5hz-MWlz-WdzV-hg2lMF/GAVDs1-caOS-pBlM-bQsb-MDyN-2LdM-nyQveG' not found
grub rescue>
```

**Why can grub not unlock my LUKS drive while cryptsetup can? How can I fix grub so it can?**

*I understand this is technically an XY problem but I have tried solving X (Kali installer failure) without success as it seems no one else has my issue, and I am so close to solving Y at this point I don't think it matters. Plus I want to learn more about grub.*

Edit: luksDump info

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda3
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          3
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           f0b2bee7-9566-4178-9a3a-6ffee87482df
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 4096 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2id
    Time cost:  4
    Memory:     1048576
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       73 ... 12 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:32768 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha256
    Iterations: 77101
    Salt:       c2 ... 80 
    Digest:     c7 ... 43
```

Comment: cryptsetup luksDump? grub2 doesn't support argon2id keyslots, requires pbkdf2 keyslot

Comment: @frostschutz Sooo... seems I have keyslot zero at PBKDF: argon2id which is probably the issue. Digests 0 shows pbkdf2 though. What do I need to do during luks setup differently to ensure I don't get argon2id set for my keyslot? Or, is there some sort of newer grub version that does work with argon2id?